# Should C topics be kept to a single function?

Tags: discussion, documentation

The C documentation has good quality topics but most are centred around just that, topics (e.g. string manipulation). Looking at the sections a topic has - remarks, syntax, parameters, etc - it seems like *most* topics should more properly document only a single function.

[String manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/370/string-manipulation) is a topic that refers in the large majority solely to string handling functions. It is  good example for a topic that I would consider would be better split into function specific topics. A user may search for documentation on `strlen` but may not search for "String Manipulation".

[Generic selection](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/571/generic-selection) seems like it is more correct in this sense - it documents **a** keyword and all sections are specific to that.

Some topics obviously would not fit well to this specificity idea, such as [Operators](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/256/operators) or [Undefined Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/364/undefined-behavior), not only do some sections not apply to the latter, but having separate topics for each behaviour or operator would make it next to useless for users searching the documentation.

Should topics where this *does* apply be split?

**EDIT:** Another option, Maybe the functions should be documented as topics, but topics such as String Manipulation are still valid in terms of advising on best practice when using such functions together or to achieve a given end? Or maybe that's what secondary examples should be used for?

Comment: How does the C and C++ documentation compare with http://en.cppreference.com/w/ ? That's my preferred online reference at the moment...

Comment: Cppreference has an overview that equates to library level then a topic per function. SO documentation at the moment picks and chooses from those approaches based on the authors whim.

Answer (score 4):

When thinking about the size and scope of a topic, put yourself in the shoes of someone learning or refreshing their memory. It's been a few years since I did any string manipulation with C, so it would be good to be reminded that:

- strings are really null-terminated character arrays,
- `char *` is a pointer so you have to declare storage somewhere else,
- string manipulation is pointer arithmetic under the hood,
- some functions copy strings and others mangle them in place, and
- a list of commonly used string manipulation functions.

Since you asked this question, someone added a [strtok example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/370/string-manipulation/2557/strtok-strtok-s#t=201607191647523651597) that covers most of those points. (I had written them before looking back at the topic.) A couple more examples and/or some remarks might fill in the gaps. So I don't think each topic in C should be dedicated to a single function.

That said, *some* functions would make very good topics. Topics tend to not work so well with a dozen examples, as the [Operators](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/256/operators#t=201607182330505660516) topic illustrates. So I wouldn't want to see the topic fill up with *every* way strings can be manipulated in C. It's also fine if some C functions are never documented on Stack Overflow as long as we have good coverage of C features that people actually use.

Comment: It was me that wrote the `strok` example, and while I was writing it I was thinking "this should be a topic by itself". The example could be split into at least 3 examples that show the different aspects of one function's behaviour, some of which are version specific and have a given syntax. But it is still string manipulation so it doesn't have its own syntax or remarks section to contain each little nugget of complexity... I was thinking a general string topic for things similar to what you mention, then individual topics for each string function would suit more use cases?

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me that, the way the organization of documentation works right now, we are either going to have individual bloated topics, with very many examples, or a bloated number of topics within each language. Having a bloated number of topics (i.e. leaning on the side of individual functions as topics) is preferable to me since it doesn't appear that you are meant to browse through the list of all topics the same way you are to browse through the list of examples on a topic (i.e. all examples are visible on one page). Broader concepts could have their own topics and could redirect users to topics pages for specific implementations of the concepts.

That being said, clearly people have different opinions on the matter, and some sort of standard should be reached.